# jquery submitting form within if statement

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

When i click each of the buttons it displays a different form. Depending on which button was pressed, a different form is submitted. This is all displayed in a dialog, but when i click send nothing happens. Can someone people help me figure out whats wrong?

this is the jquery that submits the form

```
     $( "#contact_form" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 600,
          width: 500,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Send": (function() { 
                if(submitbutton == 1){            
                    $("#schedule_info").submit(function () {
                     sendContactForm();
                     $( this ).dialog( "close" );})
                }

                else if(submitbutton == 2){           
                    $("#contact_info").submit(function () {
                     sendContactForm();
                     $( this ).dialog( "close" );})
                    }

                else if(submitbutton == 0){ 
                    $("#error").css("display", "");
                }

            }),
```

This is the jquery that changes the active form:

```
        var submitbutton = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $( "#schedule_trigger" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                 $("#schedule_info").css("display", "");
                 $("#contact_info").css("display", "none");
                 $("#error").css("display", "none");
                 $("#schedule_trigger").blur();

               submitbutton = 1;

              });
            $( "#contact_trigger" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                 $("#schedule_info").css("display", "none");
                 $("#contact_info").css("display", "");
                 $("#error").css("display", "none");
                 $("#contact_trigger").blur();
               submitbutton = 2;

              });
            });
```

This code worked perfecetly fine before i added a second form to my dialog

```
     "Send": (function() { $("#contact_info").submit(function () {
         sendContactForm();
          return false;
          }); 
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }),
```

Comment: `$(this).dialog("close")` is never called because of the `return false` before it.

Comment: Why the return false inside the function?

Comment: Taking the return false out didnt change anything, when i click send it doesnt submit the form nor does it close the dialog. i think it had something to do with the submitbutton value but i of course am probably wrong

Comment: Taking the return false out didnt change anything, when i click send it doesnt submit the form nor does it close the dialog. i think it had something to do with the submitbutton value but i of course am probably wrong

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: nope, it says there's nothing wrong. any other ideas?

Comment: Also, the error thing does display when submitbutton=0 so it has to be an error in the submit function, not the send: function

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.submit()` on a jQuery object does not submit the form. It registers an event handler for the form's "submit" event.

To submit the form, you need to call `.submit()` on the actual form element, like this:

```
$("#schedule_info")[0].submit()
```

---

UPDATE:

If you do not want to leave the current page, you cannot submit the form as shown above. It must be submitted via ajax.

There is no way, however, that your old code worked. It would have closed the dialog, but it would not have submitted the form. It would have also registered an event listener that would have executed had the form been submitted by some other means. That would never happen, though, since there is no submit button for the form. And if the event listener had been executed, it would have caused an error because the `sendContactForm()` method does not exist.

If you now want to submit the form via ajax, you can do something like this:

```
"Send": (function() { 
    if (submitbutton == 1) {            
        var $form = $('#schedule_info');
        $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
            type: $form.attr('method'), // You could just hard-code this to 'post'.
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'html', // This causes the "response" parameter to the success
                              // callback to get left as a string. Change to 'json'
                              // if you want the response automatically parsed to an
                              // object.
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response); // Handler the response here.
            }
        });
        $(this).dialog("close");
     } else if (...
```

Comment: this worked before i split the form up, but what is the other way to do it? If it would help to see the site the url is laserawayfat.com

Comment: @TylerRichardson - What does `sendContactForm()` do? I don't see it in the page source.

Comment: im really not sure... i grabbed it off of some example code. taking it out didnt change anything

Comment: @TylerRichardson - Well, good, then it won't break anything when you remove it. :)

Comment: actually the 
sendContactForm();
return false 
is what keeps from the user being directed to the action page, with this script the dialog just goes away instead of the user being send elsewhere. HOWEVER, i put in the [0] and tried the script both with and without the redirect script and it did submi the form but now it is sending the user to the mailer.php page.

Comment: @TylerRicharson - I will add to my answer.

Comment: do i need to define the sendContactForm()? also is the return false necessary still?

Comment: @TylerRichardson - Yes, you will need sendContactForm(). It sounded like it existed before.

Comment: @TylerRichardson - I'm guessing the `return false` was needed when the form had an actual submit button. But with the code you have now, the form is submitted when the user clicks the "Send" button, which is not a submit button for the form. Therefore, `return false` is not needed.

Comment: the sendContactForm() never existed, i have no idea how it was working before. how would i go about defining it?

Comment: @TylerRichardson - Without seeing the original code, it's hard to say how it was working before. But unless a form is submitted via ajax, the user is going to leave the current page (although it could be that the current page is redisplayed). I have added to my answer to show how a form can be submitted via ajax. You have to decide how to handle the response though.

Comment: @TylerRichardson - I had a mistake in the ajax code. It should be "action", not "href".

Comment: but how do those two codes interact? i dont see where sendMakeApptForm is being defined as a function that submits the form

Comment: @TylerRichardson - You need to define the sendMakeApptForm() function. The ajax code would go inside it. Then define the sendContactForm() function in a similar manner for the other form.

Comment: @TylerRichardson - I have a feeling, though, that the form was was not previously being submitted via ajax. Are you sure the current page was not reloaded after the user submitted the form? If the form was not submitted via ajax before, you can't just switch to it now without also modifying the response. If the form wasn't submitted via ajax before, the response will be an entire html page.

Comment: I can just duplicate the home page on the mailer.php but that opens a whole can of worms that would make the system very messy. Before i believe the page reloaded but as of now it is taking the user to the mailer.php page which is blank

Comment: i updated my question with the script i used to have within my send button

Comment: @TylerRichardson - Sorry, but I simply do not believe that your old code really worked. That is, it may have closed the dialog, but there is no way it submitted the form.

Comment: Haha it did i promise, i dont know how but it did. I still have the old code on the submission forms on all of the other pages